# How stanford-nlp distinguishes between abbreviation dot and full stop?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

in this link http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.html
a document is processed and all abbreviation dot and full stop are recognized differently. I want to know the logic or process used behind this. Please explain.

Comment: If you want to learn about the tokenizer you'll need to look at this file: edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex.  You can find a link to that file on GitHub here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex

Answer (score -2):

You can split your document to sentences (using Stanford or any other tool, e.g [this](https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/illinois-cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/core-utilities#accessing-sentences)); clearly the dots at the end of sentences are full stops.

Comment: It is not clear to a machine which dots are at the end of sentences. Hence the OP's question.

Comment: For example: `Hello world. My name is Mr. Smith. I work for the U.S. Government and I live in the U.S. I live in New York.`. It is by no means a simple task to differentiate between an abbreviation dot and full stop. This is why different segmentation tools have different accuracies and will produce different results.

Comment: Plus you run into examples like in the one I gave above where an abbreviation ends a sentence, in which case `"When an abbreviation with a period ends a sentence, that period will suffice to end the sentence."`.

Comment: That's the whole point of sentence splitter systems; they are designed to distinguish between the dot in "U.S" and the full stop dot...

Comment: Have you tested them? I don't think they are nearly as reliable as you think, especially when it comes to edge cases. I have tested many including Stanford, you can see the results [here](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter#comparison-of-segmentation-tools-libraries-and-algorithms).

Comment: You can test this one too on your data. I'm curious to see the result.